# Getting some issue like Cleaning up unclosed ZipFile for archive in excel file when run the Automation code

Tags: java, selenium

So I've been working on a simple automation framework that uses excel as data pool. However, while updating the version of my pom.xlm, I've encountered this error in my console:

> Cleaning up unclosed ZipFile for archive  D:\ExcelData\RPC Standard Form Data1.xlsx

I have no idea what went wrong. This error does not stop the execution and my tests run smoothly. How can I possibly solve this problem. I can't find anything suitable answers

Here my dependencies

```xml
<project>
    <groupId>com.manuhsolutions</groupId>
    <artifactId>Seleniumtest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here's the method I deal with the excel:

```java
package automationcode;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class OpenXlsxFile {

     static XSSFWorkbook workbook;
     static XSSFSheet sheet;

     public OpenXlsxFile (String excelPath, String sheetName) {

         try {
             workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelPath);
             sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }

    public static void main (String [] ags) {
        getRowCount() ;
        getCelldataString(1,1) ;
        getcolCount() ;
    }

    public static int getRowCount() {
        int rowCount = 0;
        try {
            rowCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
            System.out.println(exp.getCause());
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rowCount;
    }

    public static String getCelldataString(int rowNum, int colNum) {
        String cellData = null;
        try {
           cellData = sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colNum).getStringCellValue();
        } catch (Exception exp) { }

      return cellData ;
    }

    public static int getcolCount() {
        int colCount = 0;

        try {
          colCount = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
            System.out.println(exp.getCause());
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

        return colCount ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code sample does not include any ZipFile. So I guess in some other place in your code you are working with `java.util.zip.ZipFile` which needs to be closed `zipFile.close()`. Look closer to your stacktrace or add it to the question.

Comment: An xlsx file is a zip file, actually... Your problem might be caused by not closing the workbook and all io streams to/from it. Do you ever call `workbook.close()` anywhere? Ok, it would be a logical consequence from a `class` called `OpenXlsxFile` not to close an xlsx file. Do you have a `class CloseXlsxFile`?

Comment: 'An xlsx file is a zip file' @deHaar is right, that will be it. Anyway always check all warnings and fix proposals.